# Optimizing calculating combination and avoiding overflows

Tags: c, overflow

I am solving a programming problem which is stuck at calculating `nCr` efficiently and at the same time avoiding overflows. I have made the following trivial simplification but am just curious about if there are any more sophisticated simplifications available out there.

`(n)!/(n-k)!*k! = n*(n-1)*.....*(max(n-k+1, k))/(min(n-k, k-1))`

Can there be any more simplification possible considering different cases for k as even or odd, just suggesting a way.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: As an alternative/complementary answer, the GMP library can be used to represent arbitrarily large integers. http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an interesting solution here: http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html

```
    unsigned choose(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
      unsigned r = 1;
      unsigned d;
      if (k > n) return 0;
      for (d=1; d <= k; d++) {
        r *= n--;
        r /= d;
      }
      return r;
    }
```

This avoids overflows (or at least limits the problem) by performing multiplication and division alternatively.

E.g. for `n = 8`, `k = 4`:

```
result = 1;
result *= 8;
result /= 1;
result *= 7;
result /= 2;
result *= 6;
result /= 3;
result *= 5;
result /= 4;
done
```

Comment: I understand the approach and thought about it before posting it but could not prove that when you are dividing with some number say `x` in some iteration then why is necessary that numerator at that time is a multiple of `x`. If it is not a multiple then we will not get correct answer.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: After the divide statement in each iteration of the loop, r has the value nCd, for the original value of n and the current value of d. Thus, when n starts at 10, the first iteration sets r to 10 (*10 / 1). The second iteration sets r to 45 (*9 / 2). The third iteration sets r to 120 (*8 / 3). These are the values 10C1, 10C2, and 10C3. And we know that nCd is always an integer. Therefore, the mathematical division must always produce an integer, so, before the division, it must be true that r is a multiple of d.

Comment: This still overflows very quickly. `(((((((((99 / 1) * 98) / 2) * 97) / 3) * 96) / 4) * 95) / 5) * 94 = BOOM`

Comment: @Dici: if this overflows, then the overall result overflows as well (given your `k` ranges only from `1` to `n/2`, which is enough to compute the result for any `k`)

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem, too. What I did was use the fact that there are the same number of multiplications as divisions and bundled them together, taking one multiplication and one division at a time. It comes out as an integer at the end, but I use double for the intermediate terms and then round to the nearest integer at the end.

```
// Return the number of combinations of 'n choose k'
unsigned int binomial(unsigned int n, unsigned int k) {
unsigned int higher_idx;
unsigned int lower_idx;
if(k > n-k) {
    higher_idx = k;
    lower_idx = n - k;
} else {
    higher_idx = n - k;
    lower_idx = k;
}
double product = 1.0;
double factor;
unsigned int idx;
for(idx=n; idx>higher_idx; idx--) {
    factor = (double)idx / double(lower_idx - (n - idx));
    product *= factor;
}
return (unsigned int)(product + 0.5);
}
```